# Determine Cluster Label in K-means

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have dataset that is contain 150 data that is actually divided into 3 group. Each group has it’s own label.

I do clustering process with K-means algorithm to group the data.

I need to assign the label of each group that is created by K-means process. So I could compare the result of K-means with the data training.

Anybody could help to explain how to determine the label of each group?

Comment: Wouldn't be more appropriate to ask it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Leonardo why? I don't think programmers is more appropriate.

Comment: (If any other site, cross-validated would be the most relevant IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [cluster evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Evaluation_and_assessment) in Wikipedia.

No clustering algorithm will assign a label such as `iris_setosa` to the cluster, unless you provide the labels to the clustering algorithm somehow (but then it is no longer clustering, actually, but classification).

So you will only have `first_cluster`, `second_cluster`, `third_cluster` type of labels.

There are various measures proposed to compare the *structure* of the clusters in comparison to the original data set. But **usually there will not be a 1:1 correspondence** to the original labels.

Comment: As I absolutely new in learning about clustering, may I know some of the measures that is proposed to compare the structure of the clusters in comparison to the original data set?

Comment: Read the **Wikipedia article** linked above. It is meant for people new to clustering...